# Install4J VM detection fails on Mac

Tags: install4j

We're getting ready to deploy our app (Cytoscape) using Install4J7's feature that detects the installed JVM and offers to download a new one. We find that if we download a JVM, let the installer finish, then run the installer again, it offers to download a new JVM again. I would have thought it would have detected the one it just downloaded.

**Have we misconfigured something?? Or is there a later version of Install4J?**

Our JVM range is 1.8.0_152 .. 1.9.

The JVM we're downloading is here: http://chianti.ucsd.edu/jres/macosx-amd64-1.8.0_162.tar.gz

**What could be going wrong??**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior. The installer does not look for existing installations and use their JVM, it downloads the bundled JVM if not suitable JVM was found in the search sequence.

Comment: Thank you. OK ... to be completely clear ... the first execution of Install4j didn't find a suitable JVM. So, it downloaded one, stored it, and used it. The second execution of Install4j didn't find a suitable JVM, even where it stored the first copy. And so it downloads another copy. Is this expected, or should the second invocation have found the JVM created by the first invocation? Follow on ... why wouldn't the second invocation find the first copy and use it?? Thanks!

Comment: It does not store the downloaded JRE for use by other invocations of the installer. The JRE is extracted in the temporary directory and copied to the installation directory after the installation.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have not selected 32-bit for your application and then downloaded a 64-bit JDK. Or vice versa.